# BizTalk 2020 SB-Messaging SBMP/AMQP protocol

Tags: biztalk, azureservicebus, biztalk-2020

We've started our journey on a hybrid setup where we use a BizTalk on-prem and other teams in the company is working in Azure and want to use BizTalk as the glue between on-prem stuff and Azure, and since Service Bus is the new hyped thing, everyone is talking about that's where eve-ryone is going because messages can be handled async.

My team didn't get much choice in terms of talking solutions etc. how to handle this, the other simply decided to just go with a service bus straight up and pay for a premium tier to allow filers larger than 256kb, however even in BizTalk 2020 the SB-Messaging adapter does not allow larg-er than 1 MB because it runs on the SBMP protocol and not AMQP as the later SDK versions which is described on Microsoft’s own documentation.

We would have preferred to use AzureBlobStorage adapter with an event driven design that send a message to the SB that a message is available, but we’re force by their choice to go with a service bus, however since we’re limited to 1MB size because of the protocol and it seems like Microsoft does not plan on implementing AMQP protocol for the SB-Messaging anytime soon, CU4 does not change anything.

I was wondering if anyone else has found ways around this other than just straight up code our own adapter since each internal department doesn’t talk with each other at Microsoft and get-ting our internal to change their mind is a challenge on its own.

Tried updating BizTalk and searching far and wide if anything has solutions for this, I'm hoping for a workaround or just the confirmation that we need to develop our own SB-Messaging adapter that supports AMQP

Comment: We have the exact same issue and we are moving out of Biztalk, and as per your explanation, the AzureBlobStorage blob is not a proper solution because it does not guarantee the event sequence and reliability. Just to clarify, what technology stack do you prefer? Based on that, I will provide some solutions, and please let me know what source systems you expect to receive data from.

Comment: It is true that the AzureBlobStorage is not a way to guarantee the ordered delivery, but my general consensus is that systems should be able to handle that, at least if their of newer dates, even more so if the file contains data when its relevant for. the way we're going about it is coding our own adapter with AMQPNetLite.

Answer (score -1):

Why are Dijkgraaf editing the text of others?
I removed my solution to this problem after have being edited myself.